# Android - Retrofit web service value problems

Tags: java, android

I have phone contact numbers list stored in an array and called `contactsString[]`

and in an online database registered users numbers

I want to count how many registered users are there

and there is my code

```
            for (i=0;i<contactsString.length-1;i++){

                Phone phone=new Phone();
                phone.phone=contactsString[i]
                WebService.getInstance().getApi().checkNumber(phone).enqueue(new Callback<MainResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MainResponse> call, Response<MainResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body().status==1){
                            availableUsers++;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MainResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    }

                });
            }
```

my problem is the web service response is delayed so it don't count and `availableUsers` is printed it's initial value which is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try better sending an array of `Phone` objects. In this way you would get the correct answer in 1 call.

I would never do this in the way you implemented: imagine you have 500 contacts: you will be doing 500 calls to your server. Now imagine you have 100000 users with 500 contacts each

Comment: how to send all the array to server ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to customize your api call in this format. Which uses async task class.

```
private void phoneContact() {
        new AsyncTask<String,Void,String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String ... params) {
                try {
                    Platform http = Url_Contacts;   
                    JSONObject resp = http.search(what,where);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + resp.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                return "";
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your service works well and the format of json with value status in there.
In onResponse, run on UIThread to update your View with the availableUsers.

Comment: Did you just put a breakpoint or write the log to make sure that the code run to availableUsers++;? 
If it works, just create runOnUiThread to update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

The enqueue method is asynchronous. So your code should respect the multithreaded nature of it.

There are many approaches you can take:

1. Replace enqueue() method with execute(). But that makes all the calls synchronous. If you call it in UI Thread then whole app can stutter. Probably you will get NetworkOnMainThreadException. Not a good approach anyway.
2. Use RxAndroid or RxJava with Observer pattern.
3. Simple solution. Create a variable `int callsFinished = 0;`. In onResponse increment that variable. Then if that `callsFinished == contactsString.length` that means all calls have been done.
   In your activity add a listener

```
    void onAllCallsFinished(int availableUsers) {
        //do what you want with availableUsers information
    }
```

Call `onAllCallsFinished(availableUsers)` when `callsFinished == contactsString.length`.
There you can do what you want with that data. Update a view, call another service.